# Create link to Sitecore Item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I know I have done this before but I can't seem to remember where or how.

I want to create a link to an Item in Sitecore.
This code:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itm = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(someID);
return itm.Paths.Path.ToString();
```

Produces the following string:

```
http://localhost/sitecore/content/Home/Item1/Item11/thisItem
```

I would like to have this string instead:

```
http://localhost/Item1/Item11/thisItem.aspx
```

What is the correct way to get the path to the item? In this case I can't use a normal Sitecore link:

```
Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Link
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're needing this one, assuming you're running Sitecore v6 or anything more recent (tested with 8.2-6, should work with 9 too):

```
Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are still using Sitecore 5.3, you can use this.  Be warned this method is deprecated in Sitecore 6.0.

```
string url = item.Paths.GetFriendlyUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Web Control:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkItem" runat="server">
    Item
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Your Code:

```
var homeItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");
HyperLinkItem.NavigateUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(homeItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render item link as below:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itm = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(someID);
return Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(itm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hlItem" runat="server">

    </asp:HyperLink>
```

aspx.cs

```
   Sitecore.Data.Items.Item itm = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");

    hlItem.Navigateurl =sitecore.links.linkmanager.getitemurl(itm);
```

Answer (score -6):

You can do by this also:

```
Item.Paths.FullPath
```

It is same as:

```
Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
```

Comment: No, it's not the same at all. FullPath returns the item path, GetItemUrl() uses the LinkProvider to create a friendly URL.