# How to generate an URL to Link to content item - sitecore

Tags: c#, url, sitecore, sitecore7, email-notifications

I have trouble generating the url using

```
string.Format("/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?id={0}&la={1}&fo={0}",contentItem.ID, contentItem.Language)
```

This generates something like a path to the item but not an actual url that redirects to the content. Am I missing any settings? I really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? The code snippet indicates that you are working inside the content editor, and you have tagged the question with 'email-notifications', but your question doesn't mention either.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674308/create-link-to-sitecore-item/675101#675101

Answer (score 0):

If its a media item which you want URL of

```
   Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase ("master");
    Item item = master.GetItem ("/sitecore/media library/Images/XXX");
    If (item! = null)
    {
        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem (item);
        img.ImageUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl (mediaItem);
    }
```

If its a content item you can simply append the path like http://{yoursite}/{path relative to home item}

Comment: thanks.. i am actually trying to send a link to content in email notifications.In the workflow if a user submits content an email will be sent to approvers with a link to the item. I tried string.Format("/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/default.aspx?id={0}&la={1}&fo={0}",contentItem.ID, contentItem.Language) but this generated a path to the item but not a link..can you provide an example for generating content link..sorry if this is a basic question..jus started with sitecore..

Comment: how do i append http://devsite.com/ before the path that is generated? i tried Sitecore.Context.Site.Hostname..returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by Mark you can try the following to get the full server URL that includes the domain:

```
UrlOptions urlOptions = new UrlOptions();
urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood what exactly you are trying to achieve.
But if you want a URL of an item then I think you can use the following:

> Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);